# Eclipse indigo won't start in Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, crash

Eclipse indigo won't start in Windows 7 (first launch), the splash screen appears, stays there and nothing happens afterwards.

So far I tried the following:

- reinstall Java 6
- Add vm parameter to eclipse.ini (to the right javaw.exe path). In this case no splash screen and eclipse.exe and javaw.exe are available in Taskmanager.
- launch eclipsec.exe instead of eclipse.exe
- launch eclipse.exe -clean
- increase -Xmx384m parameter
- launch eclipse.exe in Admin Mode

No luck

My config:

- Eclipse Indigo Java Edition (32bits)
- Windows 7 (32bits)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Eclipse Indigo (and the new Eclipse Juno) work fine for me on every Win7 box I've ever tried.  Q: Windows 7 has a funky "kiosk mode", that pretty much won't let you do anything.  Are you sure you're logging in as a normal user in a normal environment ... and *not* into kiosk mode?  Q: Have you tried launch Eclipse from a command prompt?

Comment: Have you tried just wiping out eclipse and starting over? My eclipse used to do this but I just deleted and reinstalled and it worked fine. I assume there was some hidden error somewhere.

Comment: @paulsm4 what's a kiosk mode ? how to see whether i'm in this mode ? and also i tried running in admin mode with no luck

Comment: @Tim yep, there's nothing in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well something i didn't consider was the performance of the computer i was trying to start eclipse on.

The %TEMP% directory was full (300k+ files) and no java program could start as it takes a lot of time to access temporary files folder.

If i waited longer It might have started after 30-40min.

Now as i used the Disk Clean utility, eclipse starts normally in reasonable time.

Answer (score 2):

1) Since you've not had any luck so far, please try *deleting*, rebooting, and reinstalling Eclipse:

- delete your Eclipse install directory
- delete Eclipse workspace directory (EX: c:\users\MYUSERNAME\Workspace)
- reboot your PC
- reinstall Eclipse.

2) Try starting Eclipse from a command prompt; see if you get any errors.

- Check your Workspace.  Verify that it exists, that it's writable.

3) See if you have any logs under your workspace

- EXAMPLE: c:\users\MYUSERNAME\Workspace\.metadata.log

4) Follow the suggestions here:

- http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t99010.html

Comment: thank you for your response, but i believe i did all your steps.
For the workarea it's created but i didn't get any chance to select it as Eclipse never prompted me to.
Now i'm guessing it's a java problem with the OS, something is there slowing it down.
I'll let you know

Comment: yep actually that was a java problem, my bad. I had to wait longer (30-40min) to see the splash screen disappear and eclipse to start. Now that i cleaned the temp files in that particular computer it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After trying some tricks such as eclipse -clean, or eclipse -debug -console, searching for hints in the log files, removing xulrunner from the java.library.path environment, deleting some of the most recent history files and so on I found the solution. In your workspace directory perform the following steps:

```
cd .metadata/.plugins

mv org.eclipse.core.resources org.eclipse.core.resources.bak

Start eclipse. (It should show an error message or an empty
workspace because no project is found.)

Close all open editors tabs.

Exit eclipse.

rm -rf org.eclipse.core.resources (Delete the newly created
directory.)

mv org.eclipse.core.resources.bak/ org.eclipse.core.resources
(Restore the original directory.)

Start eclipse and start working. :-)
```