# Slowness in Eclipse Juno (4.2)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-juno

I've had some issues with slowness switching tabs in Eclipse 4.2 Juno and was hoping someone might have some answers. The original delay was about 10 seconds which dropped to 2-4 once I specified the java vm in the eclipse.ini file, but that's still slower than I think it should be. I've uninstalled all the addons that I thought might be offending and listed the active ones below and I believe the system to be more than adequate, but listed the specs anyway. Thanks for any help you could give me.

**System:**
Windows 7x64
1.73 Ghz i7
8 GB RAM

**Eclipse Addons:**
Eclipse Color Themes
PHP Development Tools (PDT)

**Eclipse.ini:**

```
-vm  
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe  
-startup  
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar  
--launcher.library  
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813  
-showsplash  
org.eclipse.platform  
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize  
512m  
--launcher.defaultAction  
openFile  
-vmargs  
-server  
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7  
-Xmn256m  
-Xms4196m  
-Xmx4196m  
-Xss4m  
-XX:PermSize=256m  
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m  
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Comment: Try cleaning up your temp folder using `Disk cleanup utility`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333891/eclipse-indigo-wont-start-in-windows-7

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446825/very-slow-eclipse-4-2-how-to-make-it-more-responsive

Comment: This is a known issue for Juno, but installing a optimization path will definitely mitigate it. see: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272#c212

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some known issues with UI performance in Juno. See the lengthy discussion at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272

The Juno Service Release 2 (SR2) has been released and it addresses many of the UI performance problems.

Answer (score 10):

You can install the Eclipse UI Juno SR1 Optimizations patch by following the instructions on this link, provided you are using Eclipse Juno SR1 release and are facing this slowness problem:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI/Juno_Performance_Investigation

Since the content on the above link has been updated, it does not provide the patch download part anymore. So for anyone else looking for the download details, all you need to do is install the Juno SR1 Patches--Eclipse UI Juno SR1 Optimization from the update site: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2 -using the process of Help menu -> Install New Software

Comment: I've been plagued with performance issues since 4.2, but since installing this, it is snappy and speedy.

Answer (score 3):

Change the java memory heap size. Look at the -XX:PermSize=256m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m  and change like for 1024m. 
There you go a link: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=424214

Comment: Changing this cut the startup load time by about 1/3, so I thank you, but the tab switching seems to still be as slow as before. Maybe it is just the issue with Juno.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the theme to `Classic`.

Comment: Yeah. Same issue here - the simple XML for MyBatis was hanging eclipse for minutes - I rolled back to Helios... But had some troubles synchronizing my projects with repositories. Consider that.

Comment: That change improved my Linux Eclipse Juno speed a lot!

Answer (score 1):

- disable unneeded validations (`Window -> Preferences -> Validations`).
- limit the number of visible validations (`Problems View -> Configure Content`)
- increase memory for eclipse in eclipse.ini as you did
- [enable virtual memory mapping for git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12120167/510711)
- [use the classic theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13072715/510711)

all together gave my Juno a big speed boost :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I upgraded to **Eclipse Juno 4.2.2** and my system: Intel Core 2 Quad Q9550 2.83Ghz 8,00 GB RAM Windows 7 Ultimate x64. I also use **GIT**.

When I pressed the *right mouse button on my project* it took a lot of time (~ 40s) before I could do anything.

That was until I ran *"git gc"* on my Linux server (different system) with the following result:

- *Counting objects: 6454, done.*
- *Delta compression using up to 8 threads.*
- *Compressing objects: 100% (5983/5983), done.*
- *Writing objects: 100% (6454/6454), done.*
- *Total 6454 (delta 1785), reused 0 (delta 0).*

After that I refreshed my project and since then the *right mouse button action* response is instant.

I hope this helps anyone, I just had to share this with you.

My Eclipse ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-server
-Xmn128m
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not update my eclipse with the maintenance build, but I have found an unofficial patch in the eclipse issue tracker, which made my eclipse a lot faster. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13470794/337621

Answer (score 0):

Install 4.3M4 - they've made significant speed improvements there and now I've finally made a switch from 3.8 :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had my Eclipse Juno extremely slow when there were lots of Java projects imported into it (I am talking around 45-50). What I ended up doing is:

1. Created "Working Set"s to divide the projects according to "Components".
2. Use the "Working Set"s to determine which Java projects were not needed to be "Open".
3. Close the unnecessary projects.

The end result is that Eclipse is as fast and snappy as it should be. Performance is close to that of 3.8.

Additionally, in the "Package Explorer" view within Java or Debug perspectives, I set the "Top Level Elements" to be "Working Sets" in order to have a more clear picture of where I am coding within my application.

This way search results and "Find type/Find Resource" results are snappier as well.

Answer (score 0):

My eclipse was very slow when I tried and switch between tabs (time is around 2-3 seconds). I modified my eclipse.ini this way and it does not happen anymore (my RAM is 2GB):

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Declipse.buildId=v21.0.1-543035
-Xms1024m 
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Eclipse bug taking too much CPU is caused by regexp parsing very long lines in Console, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=175888 The workaround is not to write very long lines in System.out/err.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Eclipse 4.3 gave me a huge performance boost.

Seems like they fixed a lot of performance bugs in the new release.

Comment: I've since just started using Vim instead. :)

Comment: @seagoj I shortly messed around with Emacs but it's no fun when you have to work with Java. In the end, I switched to IDEA. Eclipse 4.3 is not bad, though, maybe you can give it a second try. But if you don't have to use Java, stick with Vim. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Open Eclipse, Go to Windows>Close All Perspective then confirm and let Eclipse to restart.