# How do I speed up Eclipse Juno?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, eclipse-juno

After updating to Eclipse Juno I found that it intermittently freezes when I change views. It also becomes slow. Adjusting the Heap size does not have any positive effect on the performance.

How do I improve the performance of Eclipse?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072532/slowness-in-eclipse-juno-4-2/13072639#13072639 There are several answers over there already.

Comment: @AdamArold : I just wanted to document the issue I found after updating. Read my own answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE :** 
New performance release(SP2) for Eclipse Juno is out. So if your Eclipse Juno(4.2) is too slow or if it crashes intermittently it can be updated to SP2.

Just goto Help -> Check for Updates

P.S. Please backup your Eclipse folder before doing this.

**ORIGNAL ANSWER:**

This is a known issue in Eclipse Juno and there is a patch released for that. Installing this fixes the performance issues -

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI/Juno_Performance_Investigation

**Quote**

> Several major performance defects have been addressed in the Juno SR2
>   stream (4.2.2). Community members have confirmed that these fixes
>   substantially address the performance problems with editor and view
>   opening, closing, and switching. These fixes will be widely available
>   in the Juno Service Release 2 (February 2013) and Kepler (June 2013)
>   releases. Meanwhile, a patch is available for those using Juno SR1
>   that provides early access to these fixes. To install this patch:
>
> Ensure you are already running on a package from the Juno SR1 release
>   (September 2012) Invoke Help > Install New Software Select this
>   repository: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2 Expand
>   Juno SR1 Patches and install Eclipse UI Juno SR1 Optimizations To
>   repeat, this patch is only intended for users of the Juno SR1 release.
>   *If you have a Juno SR2 maintenance build from November 21 or later, or
>   Kepler stream milestone M4 or later, this patch is not required.*

Comment: i don't see Juno SR1 patches in the repository.  I'm currently running Juno SR1

Comment: @duvo : Updated my answer with latest steps.

Comment: Kepler is to be much faster. What's new docs reference speed improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to Eclipse Kepler 4.3 is a no brainer, it's much faster than the Juno release because the Eclipse team has indeed fixed the performance defects. I personally ended up installing my entire development environment including the JDK and Eclipse on a RAM drive.

Eclipse now starts in under 10 seconds and overall performance has improved dramatically. I documented my approach here:

http://www.whizu.org/articles/how-to-install-eclipse-on-a-ramdrive.whizu