# eclipse juno ADT 21 - slow switching tabs

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

My eclipse is very slow when I try and switch between tabs (time is around 2-3 seconds).
While i switch between tabs I see the icons "reload dependencies" and "grammar check" toggling
This is my configuration: 
eclipse=Juno; adt-bundle=adt-bundle-windows-x86; adt version= 21

Comment: Common Juno performance problem, [please see this question, the accepted answer and my post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072532/slowness-in-eclipse-juno-4-2/14342534#14342534).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly what can happen with your eclipse. In my Mac Pro is working perfectly but is true that sometimes I can feel that slow switch between tabs.

Anyway, my answer is...there is a new environment, Intellij Idea. Maybe, at the beggining, it is a little bit more difficult to set the android sdk and to manage...but come on, it is super fast...faster than eclipse...and the interface is super nice...if you can not work properly with eclipse, at least, let you know that you have this choice.

I didn't use too much it because I am programming also for iOS but the two super nerds that we have in my company, they are already using Intellij Idea.

hope this help you, maybe in the future.  (You welcome for the points, :) )